# Get position of dynamically created child view after clicking on it

Tags: android

I am inflating layout dynamically according size of my list. And now whenever i click on that dynamic view i have to get position of clicked child view. I am trying this code but my bad luck...

```
    LinearLayout layoutViewDealsList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.baseLinearLayoutSiteHistory);
    txtViewNoDeals = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNoDeals);

    if(dealsList != null && dealsList.size() > 0) {
        for(int index = 0; index < dealsList.size(); index++) {
            txtViewNoDeals.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) profileActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_row, null);

            txtViewDealsPrice = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealPrice);  
            txtViewDealsTitle = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealTitle);
            txtViewDealsDescription = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDescription);
            txtViewDealsBuyer = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealBuyer);
            txtViewDealsDate = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDate);

            txtViewDealsPrice.setText("Price: $" + dealsList.get(index).getDeal_amount());
            txtViewDealsTitle.setText(dealsList.get(index).getTitle());
            txtViewDealsDescription.setText(dealsList.get(index).getDesc());

            layoutViewDealsList.addView(layoutView);
            int position = layoutViewDealsList.indexOfChild(layoutView);
            layoutViewDealsList.setTag(position);
            appDelegate.setDealsList(dealsList);
        }
    } 


    layoutViewDealsList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position  = (Integer) v.getTag();//layoutViewDealsList.indexOfChild(layoutView);
            Toast.makeText(profileActivity, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

I am unable to know that where i am doin wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? get position of what ? child which is clicked ? you set OnClickListener to layoutViewDealsList. why ?

Comment: yeah i have to get position of child view.

Comment: needed some more explanation what you want??

Comment: @kalyanpvs when i click on child view i have to get the position of clicked child view

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj Means which childView is there at position where you click layoutViewDealsList ?

Comment: @Prince yeah exactly. i have to get that position only

Comment: why are you putting listener for whole linear layout?

Comment: i also tried to put listener for only child view but it didn't work.

Comment: layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}); use listener like this.

Comment: will you explain it a bit & also clarify your problem please? and just put some more code which is related to it so i can help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to apply onClickListener in your layoutView inside loop.

```
LinearLayout layoutViewDealsList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.baseLinearLayoutSiteHistory);
txtViewNoDeals = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNoDeals);

if(dealsList != null && dealsList.size() > 0) {
    for(int index = 0; index < dealsList.size(); index++) {
        txtViewNoDeals.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) profileActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_row, null);

    txtViewDealsPrice = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealPrice);  
    txtViewDealsTitle = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealTitle);
    txtViewDealsDescription = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDescription);
    txtViewDealsBuyer = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealBuyer);
    txtViewDealsDate = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDate);

    txtViewDealsPrice.setText("Price: $" + dealsList.get(index).getDeal_amount());
    txtViewDealsTitle.setText(dealsList.get(index).getTitle());
    txtViewDealsDescription.setText(dealsList.get(index).getDesc());

    layoutViewDealsList.addView(layoutView);
    int position = layoutViewDealsList.indexOfChild(layoutView);
    layoutViewDealsList.setTag(position);
    appDelegate.setDealsList(dealsList);

layoutView.setOnClickListener(this); <--------------- setOnClickListener
}
```

}

And your `onClick()` looks like..

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position  = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(profileActivity, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
```

Comment: let me try. i ll let you know :)

Comment: Glad to help you buddy :) Happy codding. And did you understand how it works ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set "OnClickListener" to each inflated view.

```
OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position  = (Integer) v.getTag();//layoutViewDealsList.indexOfChild(layoutView);
        Toast.makeText(profileActivity, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
};
LinearLayout layoutViewDealsList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.baseLinearLayoutSiteHistory);
txtViewNoDeals = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNoDeals);

if(dealsList != null && dealsList.size() > 0) {
    for(int index = 0; index < dealsList.size(); index++) {
        txtViewNoDeals.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) profileActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_row, null);

        txtViewDealsPrice = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealPrice);  
        txtViewDealsTitle = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealTitle);
        txtViewDealsDescription = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDescription);
        txtViewDealsBuyer = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealBuyer);
        txtViewDealsDate = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDealDate);

        txtViewDealsPrice.setText("Price: $" + dealsList.get(index).getDeal_amount());
        txtViewDealsTitle.setText(dealsList.get(index).getTitle());
        txtViewDealsDescription.setText(dealsList.get(index).getDesc());
        layoutViewDealsList.addView(layoutView);
        int position = layoutViewDealsList.indexOfChild(layoutView);
        appDelegate.setDealsList(dealsList);

        layoutView.setTag(position);
        layoutView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

Also notice that position is set to each layout view instead of it'a parent.

Answer (score 1):

In case much better solution is :

Set Tag First-

```
int position = layout.indexOfChild(view);
```

layout.setTag(position);

When Clicking time:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            fileDataList.remove(position);
            ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
        }
    });
```